# Ajax used in Django 

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

Hi I had just started to use Ajax and am getting an input from a textfield (id_title) in html to retrieve information from the database dynamically. It is now working fine when there is input in the textfield from the user, however when there is no input, the database still retrieves the first few records in the database. How can I prevent calling the success function when 'id_title' is empty?

Edit:

Perhaps I should add that I'm using Ajax together with the Django framework. When there is no input the first 10 records are retrieved. I'm not sure how to stop sending records to 'qna/rec_results.html' when there is no input received from 'query' at the django function.

**Django Function (Referred function at /qna/question_t_lookup/)**

```
def question_autocomplete_lookup(request):
results = []
model_results = Tags.objects.filter(name__icontains = q)
if request.method == "GET":
    if request.GET.has_key(u'query') :
        value = request.GET[u'query']
        model_results = Question.objects.filter(title__icontains = value)
    else : 
        model_results = Question.objects.all()
else : 
    model_results = Question.objects.all()

paginator = Paginator(model_results, 10)
new_rec_list = paginator.page(1)

return render_to_response('qna/rec_results.html',{'rec_list' : new_rec_list})
```

**AJax Function**

```
 function load_qn_search() {
     $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: '/qna/question_t_lookup/',
       data: {
            query: $("#id_title").val()},
       success: function(data) {              
               $('#ajax_reload_content').html(data);
       },
       statusCode: {
         500: function() {
           alert("Opps! There is a error!");
         }
       }
     });
};
```

Comment: simple validate your inputbox using validate.js .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to machaku, I was able to come out with this that caught the empty string issue! Thanks alot!

```
if len(value.strip()) > 0:
            model_results = Question.objects.filter(title__icontains = value)
        else:
            model_results = []
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function load_qn_search() {
     $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: '/qna/question_t_lookup/',
       data: {
            query: $("#id_title").val()},
       success: function(data) {
               if($("#id_title").val()=='') return false; // stop executing 
               $('#ajax_reload_content').html(data);
       },
       statusCode: {
         500: function() {
           alert("Opps! There is a error!");
         }
       }
     });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
function load_qn_search() {
    if($("#id_title").val())
    {
     $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: '/qna/question_t_lookup/',
       data: {
            query: $("#id_title").val()},
       success: function(data) {              
               $('#ajax_reload_content').html(data);
       },
       statusCode: {
         500: function() {
           alert("Opps! There is a error!");
         }
       }
     });
    }
};
```

Make the ajax call only if the text value is not empty.

Comment: I might be wrong, but, didnt `.empty()` removes the content of an element? http://api.jquery.com/empty/

Comment: Apologies for the mistake. Have made the relevant changes. Please check if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `model_results = Question.objects.all()` when query is not availabe. Try create empty model_results when query is empty.

Example:

```
if request.GET['query']:
    # return your query results
else:
    model_results = []
```

Comment: It is a good idea to use `request.GET.get('query','')` instead of `request.GET['query']` in order to avoid `KeyError` if request has no query parameter at all.